# Twitter authentication for Flutter Web

Tags: flutter, twitter, flutter-web

I've been struggling finding a way to make my web app obtaining token + secret from Twitter.

All packages for twitter login doesn't support web atm and I don't want to use Firebase.

Is there any way to achieve Twitter login for web without Firebase? And if so, how does it work?

Regards.

Comment: Did you see https://github.com/sh4869/twitter.dart ?

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer, but it seems like this package is only compatible for iOS and Android!

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/twitter_api

Comment: Sadly there is no user authentication on this one :/